# Compiling kernel fails during "dkms-build downloading zfs" with "ERROR 404: Not Found"

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, 19.10

I'm trying to build a custom kernel for Kubuntu 19.10 with a few cherry-picked patches applied. I've followed [the instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) from the Ubuntu wiki.

However when I run the last command, `fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic binary-perarch`, it fails with the following error:

```
II: dkms-build downloading zfs (zfs-dkms__all.deb)
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/zfs-dkms__all.deb:
2019-12-13 17:46:49 ERROR 404: Not Found.
http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/pool/universe/z/zfs-linux/zfs-dkms__all.deb:
2019-12-13 17:46:53 ERROR 404: Not Found.
http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/pool/main/z/zfs-linux/zfs-dkms__all.deb:
2019-12-13 17:46:57 ERROR 404: Not Found.
http://ppa.launchpad.net/andreasbutti/xournalpp-master/ubuntu/pool/universe/z/zfs-linux/zfs-dkms__all.deb:
2019-12-13 17:46:57 ERROR 404: Not Found.
http://ppa.launchpad.net/andreasbutti/xournalpp-master/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zfs-linux/zfs-dkms__all.deb:
2019-12-13 17:46:57 ERROR 404: Not Found.
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/z/zfs-linux/zfs-dkms__all.deb:
2019-12-13 17:46:58 ERROR 404: Not Found.
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zfs-linux/zfs-dkms__all.deb:
2019-12-13 17:46:58 ERROR 404: Not Found.
http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/z/zfs-linux/zfs-dkms__all.deb:
2019-12-13 17:46:58 ERROR 404: Not Found.
http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zfs-linux/zfs-dkms__all.deb:
2019-12-13 17:46:58 ERROR 404: Not Found.
EE: zfs-dkms not found
make: *** [debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk:222: install-generic] Error 1
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, try this to see if that helps:

`sudo apt-get install gawk`

The main reason for this failure is that dkms_zfs_linux_version is empty(gawk not work for user root)

check with

> sudo gawk '/^zfs-linux / { print $$2; }' debian/dkms-versions

to see if it prints the right version (For me it's zfs-linux 0.8.3-1ubuntu12.4)

```
phoenix-a300@phoenixa300-desktop:/raid/ubt-kernel/ubuntu-focal$ git grep dkms_zfs_linux_version
debian/rules:dkms_zfs_linux_version=$(shell gawk '/^zfs-linux / { print $$2; }' debian/dkms-versions)
debian/rules.d/2-binary-arch.mk:        $(if $(filter true,$(enable_zfs)),$(call build_dkms, $(mods_pkg_name)-$*, $(pkgdir)/lib/modules/$(abi_release)-$*/kernel, $(dbgpkgdir_zfs), zfs, pool/universe/z/zfs-linux/zfs-dkms_$(dkms_zfs_linux_version)_all.deb))
```